# Is there a function similar to subquery in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, subquery, match

I want to act like a `subquery` in elasticsearch.
Let's look at the example below.

1. create index

```json
PUT test_index
{
  "mappings" : {
    "properties" : {
      "human" : {
        "type" : "nested",
        "properties" : {
          "age" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "name" : {
            "type" : "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. insert into index sample data

```json
POST test_index/_doc/1
{
  "human": [
    {
      "name": "adrian",
      "age" : 24
    },
    {
      "name": "simon",
      "age" : 26
    },
    {
      "name": "michale",
      "age" : 24
    },
    {
      "name": "beom",
      "age" : 25
    },
    {
      "name": "simon",
      "age" : 24
    }
  ]
}
```

In this situation, i want to get a result if doc satisfied condition that human.name == "adrian" and human.name = "simon"
as follow

```json
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.87546873,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_index",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.87546873,
        "_source" : {
          "human" : [
            {
              "name" : "adrian",
              "age" : 24
            },
            {
              "name" : "simon",
              "age" : 26
            },
            {
              "name" : "michale",
              "age" : 24
            },
            {
              "name" : "beom",
              "age" : 25
            },
            {
              "name" : "simon",
              "age" : 24
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

but, when i try like this

```json
GET test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "human",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "human.name": "simon"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "human.name": "adrian"
                }
              }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then, result is below

```json
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Is there any way to solve this situation??

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it as follows with two nested queries as each nested document is a document of its own. So you're looking for a top-level document that has two nested documents that must match each `human.name`:

```
GET test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "human",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "human.name": "simon"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "human",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "human.name": "adrian"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```